# What is dharmic science behind legends about brick walls flying

Tags: history

In stories about Sant Dyandev and Sant Changdev it is said that Dyandev humbled Changdev, who was coming on a tiger, by meeting him on a flying brick wall. Does anyone have information about the significance of the great sant making brick wall move, other than what is on the internet/wikipedia? Something more informative than his yogic shaktis.